# Connection without answer, using PHP to Mysql remotely

Tags: php, mysql, bdd, firewall

Hi so im trying to do a conection betwen my Apache server ( Xampp instalation ) with a remotely machine with a Mysql Server.

My php code :

```
<?php
$servername = '10.4.41.164:3306';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';
$db = 'AssistMe';

echo "Pepito";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo "Connected succesfully";
}

?>
```

The error that i get :

> **Warning: mysqli_connect():** (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond

So before puting my question here i chequed that:

- If i can do a ping to the server : 
  [Ping to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZNxd.png)
- I added a user in mysql that allows conections from anywhere : [User in Mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E728e.png)
- I also allow the firewall of the server to connect from the 3306 port : [Firewall of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUnQM.png)
- And the last test was to Using Mysql WorkBench and testing if i can connect to my Mysql : [Mysql WorkBench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZiru.png)

So i dont know why i cant connect to my Mysql BDD remotly from my PHP code.

Comment: 10.4.41.162 or 10.4.41.164 ?

Comment: ^ first that. Then you're also trying with user `root` in your code while using user `admin` in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Yeep, sorry i did a lot of changes, i corrected the code. But that was not  the problem.

Comment: I think the port 3306 is default so you can skip it or specify it using the following.. mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database, $port);

Comment: Already tryied without the port. :(